# Capturing Cookies (req.headers.cookie) on homepage with Express on node

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, server-side

I am doing a basic authentication example.   I have Node, Express, and Cookie.  I make and store a cookie once the user logs in.  Upon refreshing the page, I want to use the cookie to show that the user is still logged in on the response, and provide the information related to that user.

Server side:

```
// If I put the app.get('/'.....) up here I get the response, but not the page HTML/JS/CSS/etc...

// This uses the /app as the root directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));

// Here I get the page HTML/JS/CSS/etc but can't capture the cookie
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('I want to get here');
  if(req.headers.cookie){ 
    // This parses the cookies into a usable array
    var incoming_cookies = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie);
    Person.find({...})
      .then( function(results) {
        if (weDontFindSomeone) {
          console.log('user not found');
          res.status(400).send('user not found');
        } else {
          if (incoming_cookies.uname === loggedIn.uname) {
            console.log('Starting with a cookie logged in');
            res.status(200).send(results);
          } else {
            console.log('Some other problem with cookies');
            res.status(400).send('Some other problem with cookies');
          }
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error){
         res.status(400).send('some other error in starting, error: ' + error);
      });
  } else {
    res.status(200).send('Starting from scratch.');
  }
});
```

How do I capture the cookies on the request to the homepage and use that to determine what is served to the client?

- Do I put it in the JS on the client side?
- If you want to suggest another node module, PLEASE show a working example in a plkr, fiddle, web page example, or the like.  I do better studying working code, as it has taken me a bit long to get to this pont :)

Setting the cookie, also on the server side:

```
app.post('/api/login', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Getting a login request');
  if (weValidateTheCredentials) {
    Person.find({...})
      .then(function(personResults) {
        if (personResults.rowCount === 0) {
          res.status(400).send('user not found');
        } else {
          console.log('Logging in at \'/api/login\', and sending a cookie.');
          // 3 hours max age
          res.cookie('UID', req.body.uid, {maxAge: 10800000});
          res.cookie('uname', req.body.uname, {maxAge: 10800000});
          res.status(200).send(personResults);
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error){
          res.status(400).send('some other error in logging in, error: ' + error);
      });
  } else {
    res.status(400).send('login requires a uname and pwhash');
  }
});
```

Comment: Where and how are you setting the cookie?

Comment: @mscdex posted.  Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mixing the paradigm of what should be handled by the server and what should be handled by the client.

Using Jquery addon 'jquery-cookie-master', I can check the cookie on the request of the client side with `if ($.cookie('attributeWanted')){...}`

Comment: I don't like that idea, you **never** should trust client data, it can all be modified

Comment: I don't.   I was simply trying to get BOTH the HTML and the cookies on the same request.  (your prev answer, now deleted) had me try and use two routes, for the home page!?).  That was too complicated of an answer for such a simple setup, so that is what lead me to find out I was going down the wrong path.  What I am doing is now serving the code alongside the HTML that reads the cookie.   If the client changes the code or cookies, no problem.  I still require server side authentication for all data requests, to serve more HTML and JS. I want to read some cookie attributes when serving '/'.

Answer (score 4):

The method with Cookie is a bit devious, you can use [cookie-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser), It's made for express.

It is really simple, there is a example on the home page:

```
var express      = require('express')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

var app = express()
app.use(cookieParser())

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Cookies: ", req.cookies)
})

app.listen(8080)

// curl command that sends an HTTP request with two cookies
// curl http://127.0.0.1:8080 --cookie "Cho=Kim;Greet=Hello"
```

Or with your code:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

// Add cookie parser
app.use(cookieParser());

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('I want to get here');
  if(req.cookies){ 
    Person.find({...})
      .then( function(results) {
        if (weDontFindSomeone) {
          console.log('user not found');
          res.status(400).send('user not found');
        } else {
          if (req.cookies.uname === loggedIn.uname) {
            console.log('Starting with a cookie logged in');
            res.status(200).send(results);
          } else {
            console.log('Some other problem with cookies');
            res.status(400).send('Some other problem with cookies');
          }
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error){
         res.status(400).send('some other error in starting, error: ' + error);
      });
  } else {
    res.status(200).send('Starting from scratch.');
  }
});

// This uses the /app as the root directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
```

Comment: I started with `cookie-parser`, but that didn't work. Using the same code you have provided, it still doesn't work.  I just used a simple console and it doesn't work `app.get('/', function(req, res) { console.log('I finally got here'); res.send(); //or res.status(200).send('gh')
});` It only works when its before the express definition of the root path.   I want it to use the cookies AND send the content in the appropriate path. It must be something simple.  The page is requesting the path '\' with cookies.   I am not sure that `curl`ing is the right way to do it, but if it is, please explain.

Comment: I am not even getting to the console log.  It is as if the routing fails after the definition of the root path.  This doesn't make sense for the other routes, as they work fine.

Comment: the curl-ing whas from the example, not my idea ;). I can't really see what's wrong with it, can you post your whole file?

Comment: I think I have a cloud9 instance of the basic situation at : https://ide.c9.io/chrisfrisina/cookies   (it doesn't automatically go to /app, but once you click it , it takes you there...)  Not sure this is enough, as I am just learning Cloud9 for this.   Full updated code can be found at : https://github.com/VT-CHCI/SoundOfFractions specifically the server.js at https://github.com/VT-CHCI/SoundOfFractions/blob/master/server.js

Comment: I have never used cloud9, and I have to login when I click the link. Nevermind, I fixed it by moving the static underneath the routing. You can access your page by /index.html and the / route in /. If you want to get your html on /, you'll have to rename your / route to something else

Comment: And also, you have to remove some unused variables, like incoming_cookies.

Comment: Hrm.... I updated the answer code to reflect your suggestions, and I now get into the response, but as you note, I don't get the HTML.  This was already noted in the original question though.  I don't understand how we can't get this for the homepage, as It doesn't quite make sense when you say `If you want to get your html on /, you'll have to rename your / route to something else`.  To me, when you send the req, the server should be able to respond to the same route.   I think there is something simple.  I have exhausted all of the permutations.

Comment: Well, what's happening at this moment is that the main page (located at /) has two solutions now, the HTML and the app.get('/') route. because the app.get is the first option, the HTML is skipped and the app.get send. You can access the HTML on localhost:3000/index.html, because app.get is not pointed to that. What you can do is change app.get('/') into something like app.get('/somethingelse'). This frees the / route and lets you access the html on localhost:300/

Comment: No way to serve the HTML from the app.get('/')?

Comment: yes but you have to move the authentication, which is now on app.get('/'), to something like app.get('/auth'). this frees the / route, so the html can use it